# Prestashop - Too many categories

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.7

I have too many categories loading at the same time in prestashop catalog > products page.

I want to hide them or add something like "show more" button. It takes too long to load around 20000 categories and it also won't fully load so I can't save / edit products.

I will be happy if someone could help me out.

Comment: Do you have flat structure of categories? 1 level? 
If it is nested lazy loading should be enough to overcome it.

Comment: No, I have many subcategories

Answer (score 0):

First question, Frontoffice or Backoffice you try to load your categories?

Comment: I'm trying to load categories in the Backoffice, from the admin panel.

Answer (score 0):

you are right. it is since 1.7.0 that this problem is unresolved in prestashop. in 1.6.x there was no problems with categories loading in backoffice due was used ajax. in 1.7x they reworked the product admin page and removed ajax. bad error. now prestashop is simply unfit to handle large sites with too much categories. change platform.